# <input> in modal is showing wrong values

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, dom, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal, dhtml

I have reduced my original question to a simpler example that can be reproduced on [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/OlGe/fwmj1uxv/13/).

I have a modal dialog (`#popup`) that contains some `<input>`s decorated with the class `V`:

```
<input class="V" type="number" />
<input class="V" type="text" />
```

I have a button that sets the `value` attribute of each `<input>` to some value and launches this modal:

```
<button onclick="edit();">Edit</button>

<script>
  edit = () => {
    const inputs = $(".V");
    inputs[0].setAttribute("value", "999");
    inputs[1].setAttribute("value", "998");
    $("#popup").modal("show");
  }
</script>
```

In the modal, if I change the value of an `<input>` element and close it, the next time I launch it again, the `<input>` shows the changed value instead of the explicitly set value, 999 or 998.

Why is this happening?

The problem is not there if the modal contains a single `<input>` and I use jQuery's `.val()` method to set the value.

Comment: Where's the code? And how many objects of "Project_1" do you have? (yes, it makes a big difference)

Comment: There are more than one `<input>` elements in the modal. I have reduced the problem and reproduced it in a JS Fiddle.

Comment: @OldGeezer, Try setting the value like this ```inputs[0].value = '999';``` and the forked fiddle here, https://jsfiddle.net/2xqtganu/1/

Comment: Thanks, that works. What is the reason? `setAttribute` works the first time though and when the `<input`> is not changed.

Comment: value -- "Defines a default value which will be displayed in the element on page load."  So it only works once: on page load.

Comment: At page load, the value was empty. It is set each time just before launching the modal. I have added a second Edit button in the Fiddle to set different values to demonstrate that the `<input>` values can be set dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

So you need to set each individually, here's the jQuery version

```
edit = () => {
  const inputs = $(".V");
  $(inputs[0]).val(999)
  $(inputs[1]).val("999")
  $("#popup").modal("show");
}
```

--- old solution---
This is jQuery, you can just do:

```
edit = () => {
  const inputs = $(".V");
  inputs.val(999);
  $("#popup").modal("show");
}
```

Comment: This won't work for me. I need to update each `<input>` with a different value. I used the same 999 in the example just for demo purposes.

Comment: Your updated solution works, but it would mean a jQuery search of the DOM tree every time. The suggestion by @Maniraj Murugan to use `.value` is more efficient as the list of Html elements is already available. But either method doesn't explain why `.setAtrribute("value")` works only sometimes.

Comment: I believe I explained that. VALUE only works for initial page load.